# Problems installing from disk

Tags: installation

I have 267GB of unallocated space that I want to install onto. (Installing eOS, but the installer is the same). I was going to use the option for a custom install, but didn't know where to put the boot loader. I use Windows7. I also wanted to know if I should create a new partition from Windows. Or if I can do that from the installer. Thanks!

Comment: What's eOS exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said that the installer is the same, I am just giving instructions based on my experience from installing Ubuntu.

```
I was going to use the option for a custom install, but didn't know where to put the boot loader.
```

Under the section `Device for boot Loader Install` select `/dev/sda` assuming you have only one Hard Disk.

```
 I also wanted to know if I should create a new partition from Windows. Or if I can do that from the installer
```

You can create the new partition from the installer itself.

[image]